# Adding note to specific id in ROOM database using Kotlin

Tags: android, database, sqlite, kotlin

For some reason I cannot add my notes to the database with a specific ID for each date I choose. I have been trying to fix this in my spare time for the past week or so in between studies, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

The purpose of it is to select the date from the calendarView and have specific notes for each date called on from the DB. There is more code involved, but it's not relevant, as this is where the error is occuring, in creating the entity/object(I don't know what something in a database is called).

Below is the code in my DAO. I have been trying to add an id argument in the insertNote function, but it just comes up red.

```
@Dao
interface NotesDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertNote(note: Notes)

    @Update
    fun updateNote(note: Notes)

    @Delete
    fun deleteNote(note: Notes)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Notes WHERE id == :id")
    fun getNotesByID(id: Int): List<Notes>
}
```

Below is how I am trying to create the object in the database by calling the DAO, but it crashes after the this?.insertNote(notes) line.

```
var notes = Notes(id = date, name = noteText)

with(notesDao) {
    this?.insertNote(notes)
}
```

And here is the entity I am using to create it.

```
@Entity
data class Notes(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int?,
    val name: String
)
```

I'm sorry if this is too vague.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the issue. It's just about using the date as the id.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I resolved the issue, but it's so long winded and I can't trace back all the things I change. So I will give a quick overview.

I had to change the version in the database builder class. Then I had to add a migration function also, when I did this, the database works properly and doesn't crash. Although, it still doesn't do exactly as I want as of yet.